# How to print listview table in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

[image]

Hi, I need to print my `listview`, but I'm not sure how to do it?

Comment: Include the code you have tried and where any problems are.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Class listViewPrinter

    Private lv As ListView
    Private location As Point
    Private border As Boolean
    Private title As String
    Private titleHeight As Integer
    Private hLines As Boolean
    Private vLines As Boolean

    Private WithEvents pd As New Printing.PrintDocument

    Public Sub New(ByVal lv As ListView, ByVal location As Point, ByVal border As Boolean, ByVal _hLines As Boolean, ByVal _vLines As Boolean, Optional ByVal title As String = "")
        Me.lv = lv
        Me.location = location
        Me.border = border
        Me.title = title
        Me.hLines = _hLines
        Me.vLines = _vLines
        titleHeight = If(title <> "", lv.FindForm.CreateGraphics.MeasureString(title, New Font(lv.Font.Name, 25)).ToSize.Height, 0)
    End Sub

    Public Sub print()
        'pd.Print()
        Dim ppd As New PrintPreviewDialog
        ppd.Document = pd
        ppd.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        ppd.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Structure pageDetails       ' structure to hold printed page details
        Dim columns As Integer
        Dim rows As Integer
        Dim startCol As Integer
        Dim startRow As Integer
        Dim headerIndices As List(Of Integer)
    End Structure

    Private pages As Dictionary(Of Integer, pageDetails)        ' dictionary to hold printed page details, with index key
    Dim maxPagesWide As Integer
    Dim maxPagesTall As Integer
    Dim items() As ListViewItem

    ' the majority of this Sub is calculating printed page ranges
    Private Sub pd_BeginPrint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs) Handles pd.BeginPrint
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Landscape = True
        pd.OriginAtMargins = True   'this removes the printed page margins
        pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins = New Drawing.Printing.Margins(location.X, location.X, location.Y, location.Y)
        pages = New Dictionary(Of Integer, pageDetails)
        ' Reversed MaxWidth & MaxHeight for landscape page...
        'Dim maxWidth As Integer = CInt(pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width) - (pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left + pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right + 40)
        'Dim maxHeight As Integer = CInt(pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height - (titleHeight + 12)) - (pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top + pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom + 40)
        Dim maxWidth As Integer = CInt(pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Height) - (pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Left + pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Right + 0)
        Dim maxHeight As Integer = CInt(pd.DefaultPageSettings.PrintableArea.Width - (titleHeight + 12)) - (pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Top + pd.DefaultPageSettings.Margins.Bottom + 0)

        Dim pageCounter As Integer = 0
        pages.Add(pageCounter, New pageDetails With {.headerIndices = New List(Of Integer)})
        Dim columnCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim columnSum As Integer = 0

        For c As Integer = 0 To lv.Columns.Count - 1
            If columnSum + lv.Columns(c).Width < maxWidth Then
                columnSum += lv.Columns(c).Width
                columnCounter += 1
            Else
                pages(pageCounter) = New pageDetails With {.columns = columnCounter, .rows = 0, .startCol = pages(pageCounter).startCol, .headerIndices = pages(pageCounter).headerIndices}
                columnSum = lv.Columns(c).Width
                columnCounter = 1
                pageCounter += 1
                pages.Add(pageCounter, New pageDetails With {.startCol = c, .headerIndices = New List(Of Integer)})
            End If
            If c = lv.Columns.Count - 1 Then
                If pages(pageCounter).columns = 0 Then
                    pages(pageCounter) = New pageDetails With {.columns = columnCounter, .rows = 0, .startCol = pages(pageCounter).startCol, .headerIndices = pages(pageCounter).headerIndices}
                End If
            End If
        Next
        maxPagesWide = pages.Keys.Max + 1
        pageCounter = 0
        Dim rowCounter As Integer = 0
        Dim counter As Integer = 0
        Dim itemHeight As Integer = lv.GetItemRect(0).Height
        Dim rowSum As Integer = itemHeight

        For r As Integer = 0 To lv.Items.Count - 1
            counter += 1
            If rowSum + itemHeight < maxHeight Then
                rowSum += itemHeight
                rowCounter += 1
            Else
                pages(pageCounter) = New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(pageCounter).columns, .rows = rowCounter, .startCol = pages(pageCounter).startCol, .startRow = pages(pageCounter).startRow}
                For x As Integer = 1 To maxPagesWide - 1
                    pages(pageCounter + x) = New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(pageCounter + x).columns, .rows = rowCounter, .startCol = pages(pageCounter + x).startCol, .startRow = pages(pageCounter).startRow}
                Next
                pageCounter += maxPagesWide
                For x As Integer = 0 To maxPagesWide - 1
                    pages.Add(pageCounter + x, New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(x).columns, .rows = 0, .startCol = pages(x).startCol, .startRow = counter - 1})
                Next
                rowSum = itemHeight * 2
                rowCounter = 1
            End If
            If counter = lv.Items.Count Then
                For x As Integer = 0 To maxPagesWide - 1
                    If pages(pageCounter + x).rows = 0 Then
                        pages(pageCounter + x) = New pageDetails With {.columns = pages(pageCounter + x).columns, .rows = rowCounter, .startCol = pages(pageCounter + x).startCol, .startRow = pages(pageCounter + x).startRow}
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
        maxPagesTall = pages.Count \ maxPagesWide
        items = lv.Items.Cast(Of ListViewItem).ToArray
    End Sub


    Private Sub pd_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles pd.PrintPage
        Dim sf As New StringFormat
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
        sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

        Dim r2 As New Rectangle(location, New Size(lv.Columns.Cast(Of ColumnHeader).Skip(pages(0).startCol).Take(pages(0).columns).Sum(Function(ch As ColumnHeader) ch.Width), titleHeight))
        e.Graphics.DrawString(title, New Font(lv.Font.Name, 25), Brushes.Black, r2, sf)
        sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Near
        Dim startX As Integer = location.X
        Dim startY As Integer = location.Y + titleHeight + 12
        Static startPage As Integer = 0
        Dim itemHeight As Integer = lv.GetItemRect(0).Height
        Dim bottomRight As Point

        For p As Integer = startPage To pages.Count - 1
            startX = location.X
            startY = location.Y + titleHeight + 12
            Dim cell As Rectangle
            For c As Integer = pages(p).startCol To pages(p).startCol + pages(p).columns - 1
                cell = New Rectangle(startX, startY, lv.Columns(c).Width, itemHeight)
                e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(SystemColors.ControlLight), cell)
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, cell)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(lv.Columns(c).Text, lv.Font, Brushes.Black, cell, sf)
                startX += lv.Columns(c).Width
            Next
            startY += itemHeight
            startX = location.X
            For r As Integer = pages(p).startRow To pages(p).startRow + pages(p).rows - 1
                startX = location.X
                For c As Integer = pages(p).startCol To pages(p).startCol + pages(p).columns - 1
                    cell = New Rectangle(startX, startY, lv.Columns(c).Width, itemHeight)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(items(r).SubItems(c).Text, lv.Font, Brushes.Black, cell, sf)
                    If vLines Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Left, cell.Bottom)
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, cell.Right, cell.Top, cell.Right, cell.Bottom)
                    End If
                    If hLines Then
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, cell.Left, cell.Top, cell.Right, cell.Top)
                        e.Graphics.DrawLine(Pens.Black, cell.Left, cell.Bottom, cell.Right, cell.Bottom)
                    End If
                    startX += lv.Columns(c).Width
                Next
                startY += itemHeight
                If r = pages(p).startRow + pages(p).rows - 1 Then
                    bottomRight = New Point(startX, startY)
                    If border Then e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, New Rectangle(location, New Size(bottomRight.X - location.X, bottomRight.Y - location.Y)))
                End If
            Next
            If p <> pages.Count - 1 Then
                startPage = p + 1
                e.HasMorePages = True
                Return
            Else
                startPage = 0
            End If
        Next
    End Sub

End Class
```

[Courtesy of](https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?870549-Print-a-listview-to-a-printer&s=7d9478903154ac1926c8242c49fa7cfa&p=5354785&viewfull=1#post5354785)